# Your radiant deployment recipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, radiant

Are you using Radiant CMS?

If yes, **what is you deployment strategy**?

Since lot's of configuration is stored in the database, I need to overwrite db on the server with my development db (with capistrano it is not a problem).
But this will work only if I am the only one who updates the website. And what if customer in a meanwhile has created a new page? I need to merge databases somehow.

So, how do *you* deploy your radiant website? How do you solve issue with "database merge"? This must have some simple answer, but I can't see one...

PS. It would be absolutely awesome if you share your capistrano recipe in case you use it ;)

Comment: I've been looking for the same thing. I'm potentially taking on a massive Radiant CMS site, with pages constantly being edited on live; deploying from dev / staging is going to be a nightmare without a custom script.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have none.

I'm considering taking https://github.com/ehaselwanter/radiant-capistrano-extension and tearing it apart.

I'm looking at a site that has a mass of constantly-changing pages and snippets on live; what I'd be doing is have it just update the Settings, Layouts, CSS and JS from staging or dev (for example), instead of all the Pages, Readers, etc.